# django-Imagekit adding custom watermarks

Tags: django, image-manipulation, imagekit, django-imagekit

How would i go about adding custom watermarks to pictures using imagekit .. or maybe some other package? In my django admin i need to have a choice of several watermarks that can be applied on uploaded photos. has someone done something simmilar ? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to install PIL.

Look for **paste** function from Library.
More documentation can be found on [PIL Handbook](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm)